# Save whole row into an array instate

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am a JavaScript beginner and don't know how to search exactly what I am trying to accomplish...

I have the below array, which I display on the page in a table format, row by row.

```
[
    0: {
        cuip: ".A0100",
        quantity: 38,
        ...
    }
    1: {
        cuip: ".A0102",
        quantity: 1,
        ...
    }
    ...
]
```

When user selects any item in the list, I mark the checkbox next to that row selected by the toggle below

```
  toggleRow(cuip) {
    const newSelected = Object.assign({}, this.state.selected);
    newSelected[cuip] = !this.state.selected[cuip];
    this.setState({
      selected: newSelected,
      selectAll: 2
    });
  }
```

What I end up in the state with the selected is

```
{.A0100: true, ...}
```

Which is great. so if user selects 1, multiple or all rows, I have those rows cuips saved as true in the state. Trouble is, I need to save certain values in the row like ste, clt, quantity, etc .. ie:

```
[
    {
        ...
            "cuip": ".A0102",
            "clt": "asvd",
            "ste": "v31r",
            "quantity": 3,
        ...
    }, {
        ...
            "clt": "vr13",
            "ste": "vr31",
            "quantity": 6,
        ...
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the specific row that you selected and save that in a selected array

For instance:

```
//you can have a state of selected rows
state = {
  selectedRows: []
}
toggleRow(cuip) {
    const newSelected = Object.assign({}, this.state.selected);
    newSelected[cuip] = !this.state.selected[cuip];
..
    const {selectedRows, /* this is where your data is stored -> */ rows} = this.state;
    const findSelected = rows.find(row => row.cuip === cuip);
    const selected = [...selectedRows, findSelected]
    this.setState({
      selected: newSelected,
      selectAll: 2,
      selectedRows: selected  
    });
  }
```

Sorry If I understood wrong, but is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Exactly, with one minor issue, what is rows?.. I have all data under  `this.props.Data` but this is the whole data...

Comment: Yes, so rows is your data ;) sorry about that I forgot to mention that that is your data or whatever variable you have your state.

Answer (score 3):

You can store (and later remove) a reference to your whole row instead of a boolean value to have access to every field.

```
// Sample storage and a sample row
const selected = {};
const row = { cuip: '.A0100', quantity: 38 };

// Add a row
selected[row.cuip] = row;

// Check if a row is selected
const isRowSelected = selected.hasOwnProperty(row.cuip);

// Remove a row
delete selected[row.cuip];
```

You can bind this to your state management in the same way you've already demonstrated.
See the MDN articles on [the `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the index of each row to your onChange event of your radio, when the user clicks it get the index and save it to selected array.

```
onChange = (e) => {
  // uses row index and get the selected item from the array 
  const selected = this.state.data[e.target.dataset.index];

  const selectedState = this.state.selected;

  this.setState({
    selected: [...selectedState, selected] // add  the selected item to the selected array
  })

}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        cuip: '.A0100',
        quantity: 38,
        ste: 'some value',
        clt: 'value'
      },
      {
        cuip: '.A0100',
        quantity: 38,
        ste: 'some value',
        clt: 'value'
      },
      {
        cuip: '.A0100',
        quantity: 38,
        ste: 'some value',
        clt: 'value'
      },
      {
        cuip: '.A0100',
        quantity: 38,
        ste: 'some value',
        clt: 'value'
      }
    ],
    selected: [],
    show: false,
  };

    onChange = (e) => {
      const selected = this.state.data[e.target.dataset.index];

      const selectedState = this.state.selected;

      this.setState({
        selected: [...selectedState, selected]
      })

    }

  show = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    })
  }
  render() {

    const tr = this.state.data.map((item, index) => <tr key="index"><td>{item.cuip}</td><td>{item.clt}</td><td>{item.ste}</td><td>{item.quantity}</td><td><input onChange={this.onChange} data-index={index} type="radio" /></td></tr>);
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>cuip</th>
            <th>clt</th>
            <th>ste</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{tr}</tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.show}>show selected</button>
        { this.state.show &&
          <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.selected)}</p>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```